# Expand table row and show more data. I have some script, but when I click it always open the same row with same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

Table with a lot of table rows, but when I click at any of the rows it expand me only one row with ID 1. I need every row to be expandable for itself. How?

```
<table class='table' id='myTable'>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
</tr>
<tr id='row1'>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row1">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>

<td colspan='5' id='row1-info' class='emarNote'>
    <div id='odgovor'>

        <div id='listaOdgovora'>
            <table class='table'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Sample</th>
                    <th>Sample</th>
                    <th>Sample</th>
                    <th>Sample</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

AND javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.emarNote').hide();
$('#myTable').click(function (event) {
    tr_ID = $(event.target).parent().attr('id');
    $('#' + tr_ID + '-info').fadeToggle('slow');
});
});
```

Here an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobouch/MLzYb/1/)

Comment: The fiddle looks like it's working for me. What is broken exactly?

Comment: Yes its working. When you click on first row, it shows some data, but when you click on second, or third, or n-th row, nothing happened

Comment: There aren't ids or corresponding divs to display for those... What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The id of your second row is the same as the id of your first row.