# What is wrong with this code? Select count and Where?

Tags: php, mysql, count, rows

```
<?php 

require_once "includes/db_connection.php";

$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE questionId = $id";

$query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

echo "Tabela sadrzi " . $num_rows . " redova.";

mysqli_free_result($query);

mysqli_close($db_connection); 
?>
```

With this type of code where I have `WHERE questionId = $id` statement it give me an error Undefinded index Id, and mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter. I see that a lot of time, and somehow i fix a problem, but now i really don't now. I am new, still learning, but i really dont have idea. If i delete this `WHERE questionId = $id` it is working, its show me how many rows is it in there, but i need this with Where statement where it can show me, how many records is it for the specific ID.

Comment: What's the type of questionId

Comment: But, where are you defining that specific id `$id` ?

Comment: You must pass `$id` parameter to query.

Comment: you need to define $id.

Comment: If used with a POST type form and named element is called "id", then you need to add `$id=$_POST['id'];` - if it's a GET method, then use `$id=$_GET['id'];` as an example. In your case, and based on the query, it could resemble `$id=$_POST['question'];`

Comment: Do show the form that you're using this with. Questions like these leave too much room for error.

Comment: Yes, like as Fred says, $id is from input field :). I will try this now. Thank you!!

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems and two answers.

The first is you need to define `$id`. It's not defined anywhere on your page. If you are posting or getting the variable, then you would use:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

or

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

depending on whether its get or post.

You should also sanitize any input coming from a user, never just accept it will be fine. One of the best ways to do that would be to filter it.

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

That will return either an integer or `FALSE` if anything other than an int is in ID.

---

The second problem is your `mysqli_error()`. You need to pass the resource link in, so it should be:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error($db_connection));
```

Comment: Good luck with this. I **never** put in an answer, till I know what the full picture looks like. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- you can always edit answers. It looks fairly obvious what the issue is.

Comment: True, however I only edit if I'm absolutely certain. In this case, the OP hasn't specified where the `$id` is coming from. I'm a `terrible shot in the dark` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As [Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) said, You might have had a different PHP configuration, where `request` data is automatically predefined. Normally, you need to define the `$id` yourself:

```
<?php 

require_once "includes/db_connection.php";

# It might be ID or QUESTIONID or something similar
$id = $_POST['id'];
if ( !$id ) $id = $_GET['id'];

/* You can also add ' around your request,
to prevent error when the id is actually not present at all */
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE questionId = '$id'";

$query = mysqli_query($db_connection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

echo "Tabela sadrzi " . $num_rows . " redova.";

mysqli_free_result($query);

mysqli_close($db_connection); 

?>
```

And don't forget to sanitize them before usage to prevent [sql injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks for the mention. However, your `[id]`'s need to be `['id']` ;-)

Comment: And based on OP's [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21239423/) it seems like the `$id` could be called `listaOdgovora`. But will sit and wait this one out.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, but it is not a requirement, more like a suggestion for good practice.

Comment: It's usually best to wrap with quotes, unless it's an array. And in not doing so, it could be treated as an array.

Comment: @DainisAbols If you don't it throws a notice `use of undefined constant, assumed id`, so actually yes it is required.

Comment: Using placeholders would solve the sanitization problem.

Comment: Fred-ii - look, there is two mysql tables - answers and question. I just want to show how many answers there is for every question and to show that in html table row called 'Number of answers'.